# ADD elements of an array with a given condition

Tags: c, for-loop, scanf, variable-length-array

There is an array of n students( stu[n]).If gender is boy then my code adds

- for boy `b`, 2nd,4th,6th,........even position elements of array and
- for girl `g`, 1st,3rd,5th....odd position elements of array.

1> Gender of boys denoted by b.
2> Gender of girls denoted by g.

Input info>>

1. The 1st line contains n, denoting the number of students in the class, hence the number of elements in the array.
2. Each of the subsequent lines contains the marks of n students .
3. The last line contains gender b/g;

Output info>>

The output should contain the sum of all the alternate elements of marks as explained above.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
int n,i;
scanf("%d",&n);//n denotes number of students.
int stu[n],sum=0;


for(i=1;i<=n;++i)
scanf("%d",&stu[i]);//for accepting input in array.

char gen;
scanf("%s",&gen);//for accepting input gender b/g.


 for(i=1;i<=n;i++){
 if(gen=='g' && i%2!=0){ //girl g adds alternate odd position  elements.
sum=sum+stu[i];
printf("%d",sum);
}

else if(gen=='b' && i%2==0){ //boy b adds alternate even position elements.

sum=sum+stu[i];
printf("%d",sum);
}

}
//code
return 0;
}
```

Sample Input

3
3
2
5
b

Sample Output 
8

explanation>>
marks=[3,2,5] and gender = b so it will add 3+5(even position 0,2 alternate elements). If gender in place of b is g then it will produce  output = 2.

My code is shows output of 0 in all test cases.

Comment: You say the file has multiple lines, but the sample you give is all on one line.  Is each data point in the input separated by newlines, or by space?  Details matter, and getting them accurate is important.

Comment: seperated by new lines

Comment: The data is seperated by new lines.

Comment: should i add \n to all scanf and check ??

Comment: If you use scanf, it actually doesn't matter.  But IMO you shouldn't use scanf.  The solution I give below works for each case.

Answer (score 1):

You have the major problem in

```
int n,i;
int stu[n],sum=0;
```

here, `n` being a uninitialized local scoped variable with automatic storage, the initial value is indeterminate.

Now, since the address of the variable was never taken and it has a type that can have trap representation, attempt to use the value (`int stu[n]`) will invoke undefined behavior.

You need to scan in the value into `n` first, then use that to define the VLA `stu`. Something like

```
int n,i;
scanf("%d",&n);//n denotes number of students.
 // **Note: please check for errors in input with scanf return value.**
int stu[n],sum=0;   // here, n has the scanned value.
```

That said,

```
char gen;
scanf("%s",&gen);
```

is also horribly wrong, you want to scan in a `char`, not a *string*, and with the address of a plain `char` variable, `%s` conversion specification would be UB, again. You should use `%c` and discard any whitespaces which is present in buffer altogether.

Comment: Even after edit it shows no output.Please help again.

Comment: @AYUSHAZAD Can you please show after reading the answer what you tried and how it failed?

Comment: I placed scanf on the right place  and also changed !== to != which i saw later but still compiler shows  no output.The positions of brackets may be wrong,but i dont think so.I ran it both on code chef and geeks compiler.I am a beginner and i don't deal much with pointers as i feel lack of practice and too early to apply>>like int *marks ,so i used vla and for loop.

Comment: @AYUSHAZAD It's not about pointers or not, whatever you use, make sure you're using them correctly.

Comment: Still not showing any output (%s was changed to %c)

Comment: I think i should try another question and not waste time on this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You're making things more complicated than they need to be. Here is how you can possibly do:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int mark;
    int b = 0;
    int g = 0;
    char students_marks[5];

    for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
        scanf("%d", &mark);
        students_marks[i] = mark;
    }
    for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
        if (i%2 == 0) b += students_marks[i];
        if (i%2 == 1) g += students_marks[i];
    }
    printf("Boys: %d\nGirls: %d\n", b, g);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: We can not add input {4,5,6,7,8} as the problem says  we have to accept input by user using scanf and array size can be random n;So can you please suggest some more improvement .I am a beginner and trying it to get it right  from many hours.

Comment: Loop over a `scanf` and add the value scanned to your array and you're done.

Comment: Ok I looped over scanf but still b and g are char values why did you used it in int??

Comment: Note that you don't need these `char` because the condition is whereas it's even or uneven; you pick one, the other is useless. Also in your nested `if-else` condition in your `for` loop, you do exactly the same thing.

Comment: I have to write  b or  g gender as input char  in haker rank compiler then only the if else statement will run accordingly as even or odd?? Can you  read the question again and please help  me again ?Here is the link for proper explanation https://hackerrank-challenge-pdfs.s3.amazonaws.com/66953-students-marks-sum-English?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJ4WZFDFQTZRGO3QA&Expires=1563463575&Signature=O%2FrKil3th2w7YHhoZYQRZ9Z8j5s%3D&response-content-disposition=inline%3B%20filename%3Dstudents-marks-sum-English.pdf&response-content-type=application%2Fpdf

Comment: I have to get b or g gender as an input in the hakerank compiler and then if else satement will run accordingly .You should please read the question again and see the test cases and then try again.

Comment: The last line of input info says>>last line contains gender b/g;

Answer (score 0):

You should probably not use an array, and just ignore the first data point.  It is (probably) easier to use a linked list.  Or maybe just use two lists, alternating the inputs between them.  And I would definitely not use scanf.  If you are new to C, do NOT waste your time learning the foibles of the scanf format string language.  The *only* time scanf is ever useful is in introductory courses where instructors incorrectly believe that you will be able to get input more quickly than if you spend time learning other methods.  But in fact you will end up burning more time learning when to use spaces in the format string that you saved by not learning `fread`.  After your introduction to C, you will (almost) never use scanf.  Also, it seems like a horrible design to put the discriminant at the end of the input.  The values to be summed (the gender) should be given as a command line argument.  That said, you could just do:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

FILE *
xfopen(const char *path, const char *mode)
{
        FILE *rv;
        if( (rv = fopen(path, mode)) == NULL ) {
                perror(path);
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        return rv;
}

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
        int i;
        int size;  /* Should probably be size_t.  Skipping that for now. */
        FILE *in = argc > 1 ? xfopen(argv[1], "r") : stdin;
        int sum = 0;
        if( fscanf(in, "%d", &size) != 1 || size <= 0 ) {
                fprintf( stderr, "invalid input\n" );
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        int grades[size];
        for( i = 0; i < size; i++ ) {
                if(fscanf(in, "%d", grades + i) != 1) {
                        fprintf( stderr, "invalid input on line %d\n", i );
                        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                }
        }
        char gender;
        if(fscanf(in, " %c", &gender) != 1) {
                fprintf( stderr, "invalid input on line %d\n", i );
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        if(strchr("bBgG", gender) == NULL) {
                fprintf( stderr, "invalid gender: %c\n", gender);
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        for( i = tolower(gender) == 'b'; i < size; i += 2 ) {
                sum += grades[i];
        }
        printf("sum: %d\n", sum);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this new method but I am a beginner in c language .It has been only 20 days since i sarted learning coding using books and youtube.I have not touched the chapter --file management in c which i think you have used.

Comment: file management here is extremely minimal.  If you want to remove it, just write `FILE *in = stdin`, or just use `stdin` wherever I've use `in`.

Comment: Can you give some tips to learn pointers ,maalloc,calloc dyanamic memory ,structure union which i find tough  ??Sometime i get confused and depressed weather should i read book first or watch videoes and then solve problems on hakerank .What was your strategy for quick learning and leveling up.

Comment: I don't think there's "quick learning".  For me, the process was long and arduous, with many segmentation faults.  When something bizarre happens, jump into gdb and track it down.  Mostly, though, it's trying things.  You would IMO learn more from this problem by ignoring the first input and either putting data into linked lists or reallocating an array as needed when more data arrives.

Comment: Probably because you are writing outside the bounds of the array.

Comment: Thanks William,love from INDIA

Answer (score 0):

Hmm…   i changed your code a Little bit and hope this runs as described.

```
int main() {

       int n, index, sum=0;
       int* stu;
       scanf("%d", &n); // input number of studens

       if(n>0)
          stu = malloc(n*sizeof(int)); // allocate memory
       else
          return 0;

       for(index=0;index<n;index++)
          scanf("%d", &stu[index]);

       char gen;
       scanf("%c", &gen);

       for(index=0; index<n; index++){
          if(gen=='g' && index%2!=0) {
             sum += stu[index];
             printf("%d", sum);
          } else if(gen=='b' && index%2==0) {
             sum += stu[index];
             printf("%d", sum);
          }
       }

       return 0;
    }
```